# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta SQL con fecha y hora con tipo de campo smalldatetime?

Tags: sql, servidor

Quiero hacer esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM correo where fecha = '2021/09/06 14:34:00'
```

Pero al ejecutar esta consulta no obtengo ningún registro, revise si tengo algún registro con esa fecha y si existe, entonces es la consulta. Alguien sabe como hacerla correctamente? Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Pero Buscas de esa fecha y hora especifica?

Comment: busco del 1 de septiembre al 30 de septiembre

Comment: Si la columna es un `datetime` ten en cuenta que este dato tiene milisegundos que no estás especificando en tu filtro

Comment: Primero intenta usar SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha >'2021/09/01 00:00:00' AND fecha <'2021/09/01 23:59:59' esa es la forma rudimentaria, prueba a ver si te trae datos primero

Comment: Puedes probar: `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN "2021/01/09" AND "2021/01/30"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El escenario que planteas:

```
Create table correo (
    id int primary key,
    fecha smalldatetime
    );
GO

Insert into correo (id, fecha)
values
(1,'20210925 14:34:01'),
(2,'20210925 14:33:15'),
(3,'20210925 14:35:17'),
(4,'20210925 14:36:00'),
(5,'20210925 14:34:26'),
(6,'20210925 14:37:23'),
(7,'20210925 14:34:00'),
(8,'20210925 14:34:59')
;
go
```

La tabla contiene:

[image: Resultados]

El formato de salida de la fecha, no es lo que contiene, ya que un campo datetime se almacena en binario, por tanto la manera más eficaz en la que nunca tendrás problemas con la posible configuración del lenguaje asociado a la conexión es utilizar el format `yyyyMMdd`, sin separadores.

Por ejemplo para obtener, los registros de las 14:34, ya que es un `smallDatetime`, aunque en la insert yo he puesto 14:34:01, 14:34:26 y 14:34:59, sería:

```
Select * from correo
    where
       fecha = '20210925 14:34';
```

También sería igual de válido:

```
Select * from correo
   where
      fecha = cast('20210925 14:34' as smalldatetime);
```

[image: Resultados]

Si necesitas obtener los datos del mes de septiembre, utiliza.

```
Select * from correo
where
fecha >= '20210901 00:00'
And
fecha < '20211001';
```

fecha **mayor o igual** que la primera hora del día 01 de septiembre, y **menor que** el día  01 de octubre, y así te traerá todos los registros del mes completo.

Esta misma forma, la puedes trasladar a otros tipos de dato, como datetime o datetime2.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho!!